# Nginx reverse-proxy remove a part of the path

Tags: api, nginx, proxy, webserver, reverse-proxy

Heres the code:

```
        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://37.221.214.125:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
```

It send request from this:

```
https://new.chatenium.hu
```

to

```
http://37.221.214.125:3000/api
```

the thing i want:

```
http://37.221.214.125:3000
```

Is there any way to remove the `api` in the proxy?
Thanks!

Comment: Try: `proxy_pass http://37.221.214.125:3000/;`

Comment: Still giving 404 error. See https://new.chatenium.hu

Comment: The API is working. See: http://37.221.214.125:3000/